# counting numbers finished on 4

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

What about this problem.

We consider all the numbers ending by 4, concatenated in one super number. What would be its $290_{th}$ digit ?

Could you explain your answer ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain your question? and show your work what you have done so far.

Comment: You might think about the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant).  Your number has certain similarities.  Have you written out the first couple dozen?  How many digits are contributed by the $2$ digit numbers?

Comment: The 290th digit place of what? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi! I understand that, for example in 4,14,24,34 the digits of place 6th is 3.The answer i suppose are 0,1,2,3, or 4. I don't know how do it.

Comment: @Franzz What's the $10^{th}$ digit in $4,14,24,34,44,54$? If the answer is $5$ then you can't suppose that the answer is among $0,1,2,3,4$ as you just wrote.

Comment: 0,1,2,3 and 4 are the alternative of the question.

Comment: @dxiv: I think OP means it's a multiple-choice question, with these $5$ values as options.

Answer (score 3):

From $4$ to $94$ we have $1+2\cdot9=19$ digits.

From $104$ to $194$ we have $3\cdot10=30$ digits.

From $204$ to $294$ we have $3\cdot10=30$ digits.

From $304$ to $394$ we have $3\cdot10=30$ digits.

...

From $904$ to $994$ we have $3\cdot10=30$ digits.

Altogether we have $19+30\cdot9=289$ digits.

So the digit in the $290$th place is the first digit of $1004$, i.e., $1$.